# How to document namespaces in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

How can namespaces be documented in JavaScript with jsDoc?

Here is my attempt, is this right?

```
/**
 * My special namespace
 *
 * @name my.namespace
 * @namespace
 */
$namespace('my.namespace', /** @lends my.namespace **/ {
    /**
     * Foo - does something really neat...
     * @function
     */
    foo: function() {
    }
});
```

Just to clarify, the above is used as follows:

```
my.namespace.foo();
```

Comment: I know this is really old, but i am curious. Is `$namespace` something custom of yours?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This feature is available in jsdoc3 [micmath/jsdoc](https://github.com/micmath/jsdoc). The syntax of jsdoc3 is different to jsdoc-toolkit (jsdoc2)

The following example was by Michael [jsdoc and pseudo-namespaces?](https://github.com/micmath/jsdoc/issues/21)

```
/**
* Document me.
* @namespace my
*/

/**
* My special namespace
* @namespace my.namespace
*/
$namespace('my.namespace', /** @lends my.namespace **/ {
   /**
    * Foo - does something really neat...
    */
   foo: function() {
   }
});
```